# Why is sbt current project name "default" in 0.10?

Tags: sbt

I'm using sbt `0.10` to build a Scala project using just a `build.sbt` file instead of a full configuration.

Every time I start sbt it gives me the messages as follows:

```
[info] Set current project to default-ee699e (in build file:/Users/.../project/plugins/)
[info] Set current project to default-8febe7 (in build file:/Users/.../)
```

I did set the `name` and `mainClass` settings in the `build.sbt` file, so I don't know what I need to set to get the project names `default-XXXX` go away.

EDIT: the answer given below is correct in that this is cosmetic.  If you switch to a full configuration of sbt, then it uses that project's name as opposed to `default-XXXX` however.

Comment: It has changed in 0.13 at the very least where the name of a sbt project is the name of the directory unless changed in .sbt/.scala's files.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by *"a full configuration"*? What's the content of your build.sbt (merely for the sake of completeness)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The message can be a bit misleading, it's not saying that you must "set the curent project", it's telling you what it's doing.

It sets the current project to the plugins folder, does it's stuff (compile, etc.), then sets the current project to your actual build folder and does it's thing once again.

You don't need to set anything else.